# C++ wrong content size when reading a text file

Tags: c++, ascii

So Im reading in a .txt file like this:

```cpp
std::ifstream ifs(fileName);
std::string fileContent((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
```

When I print the size with `fileContent.size()` it gives the correct result (the amount of characters) if the file contained "normal" latin text.
But I have a case where the content looks something like this:

```
H{ {ezaziznzozrzsztycydylypyux.xfxgxhxmxywbwvwwv
vSvjvkvxuAuTuztCtEtGtHtLtMtOtPtRtUtWtqsDsFsIsY�n��Y(�-�c��
�V���f�ڕ�$�=�#�K��<�<)�n.�H�#RC'{�|�vFK�K�  ?&��dzV���&հ��s��H�0�p�>��+Y�#�8,���ߓԜy2�9�k��O}e+����u�^�  �v�,%+��m��2�0��$o�"�htha����ߕ��E�$���k�=��t[Ȥ�9C!��w��T3��&��;4$���ԭ�Dr��,���t��~BH�J���_�F��Vh��{��!1��VG��ɭ��qr�%Ǣ9}@��~�z#������Z��6��&<���߾����Z��6�v��+���b��%��Tg��V���k����9Y�FuBk����5�?F,�BH�k�U����`t�I�X.���df
�T��-   |-��r�9�k��i)]��߲_��r��\sF�j�����<�t�_Ɂ�l?�P��<�~�Yd�+ee�Ź&7��k�7�~Nԭ����N�+ev��÷�c�
��J���^V�oK�+q��^����`��rz��&B����p0n.��ﬥr��;5��LJ�R��T�z   ^ҷ�a�D����t��M� ,;}VF�d>�vka����k�f5r�"��   4n)��>S�;
��a�O������9^�A2(�HF�a����ڇ�[�Z�Vh�?V9�����{{}�ɸ���������I�E%�<`��R�XHî��V�YJ�a���)C�k�_���oK�+p9"�)� �O�Ls�mJ���H����z��v3��:(�7>��+_a���YZ!���d�J��V�;�V���'S����a���2.����>Wga���IT`n�.;    j_$u��`gT=,�dr��m����Ӄ���eh���mJ�.p�sF��u���٠�"�Ԋ�����
�RBA    k>���-AjD�����R��0�>Lc�����`�2�0r�n;}��V�����z�L���;�a/�ܚ   ?"�J�~Y-&C�a���QN��B�w·j�0%`]�3Ka�8V�v���p�<�>�Ǥ�A�4`k"������:�g���)=����–����ҷ0n ���1��E8�Խ���`�tZ��q(��w�X;�~�H�l���a�sعg�n�ʷt��}c�q)�_������a����?��K�h�NV�I��3&��"�\�ҷu��ڤIi_#rp�ą��}c�qu�j�{���8·
```

When Im reading this file and printing the size (amount of characters) it gives a wrong value. In this case there are 1269 characters (I checked it with an online letter counter) but `fileContent.size()` gives 447. What am I missing?

Comment: Characters or bytes? Is the file even read successfully?

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: This gives me the impression that raw bytes are involed.

Comment: Open the file in binary mode

Comment: alright, thanks guys. What I did here was that I had a binary sequence which I cut into 8bit chunks and then converted to a sequence of characters in order to save them in a file. Is there in general anything wrong with that?

Comment: std::ifstream ifs(fileName, **std::ios::binary**);

Comment: "cut into 8bit chunks and then converted to a sequence of characters" it isn't clear what this means at all. Please show the code.